# Why is there no synchronized keyword used in Java lock implementations?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized, reentrantlock

`synchronized` is used in Java to deal with mutex sort of things. However the implementations of `Lock` interface like `ReentrantLock` in Java does not use this keyword. All the code looks just normal code. Then how does it handle multiple threads on earth?

I believe the following code pieces are related:

The `tryAcquire` method in `Sync` of the `ReentrantLock`

```
protected final boolean tryAcquire(int acquires) {
    final Thread current = Thread.currentThread();
    int c = getState();
    if (c == 0) {
        if (!hasQueuedPredecessors() &&
            compareAndSetState(0, acquires)) {
            setExclusiveOwnerThread(current);
            return true;
        }
    }
    else if (current == getExclusiveOwnerThread()) {
        int nextc = c + acquires;
        if (nextc < 0)
            throw new Error("Maximum lock count exceeded");
        setState(nextc);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

`Sync` extends `AbstractQueuedSynchronizer` and the code related:

```
final boolean acquireQueued(final Node node, int arg) {
    boolean failed = true;
    try {
        boolean interrupted = false;
        for (;;) {
            final Node p = node.predecessor();
            if (p == head && tryAcquire(arg)) {
                setHead(node);
                p.next = null; // help GC
                failed = false;
                return interrupted;
            }
            if (shouldParkAfterFailedAcquire(p, node) &&
                parkAndCheckInterrupt())
                interrupted = true;
        }
    } finally {
        if (failed)
            cancelAcquire(node);
    }
}
```

So seems no `synchronized` keyword is used then how does it guarantee mutex?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Java 1.5(?) there is JVM support for hardware locking using so called [Compare-And-Swap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap) methods. Just follow the sources until the point when this is called.

Also see Doug Lea's paper for better understanding: http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/papers/aqs.pdf

Comment: Yea. Found it and it has native keyword. So the corresponding code is actually not java?

Comment: It is in the code the JVM is written in. For Oracle this is C++, for IBM this is Java itself :-)